# C++ - If statement comparison returns error

Tags: c++, if-statement, syntax

So if I have this line of code below, it returns the error also shown below.

```
string beads = "example";

if (beads[0] == "w")

./beads.cpp:19:15: error: comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'const char *')
    if (beads[0] == "w") {
        ~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
```

However, if I change the statement to the statement below, everything works well. Why is that?

```
if (beads[0] == *"w")
```

Comment: Why do people down vote?  Its been a plague lately.

Comment: @ojblass, It *is* a rather RTFM type question tbh.

Comment: I am not saying it is dissertation material.  he provided code... he tried to help himself... he showed us what he tried.

Comment: Thanks for all the informative answers! It fixed my problem.
And sorry for my noobish question; I am pretty new to c++. I come from a Python background where " and ' do the same thing.

Comment: @ojblass We're trying to maintain a helpful Q&A site here, rather _'being helpful'_ for particular, localized, badly asked questions here! (I gave an answer myself though)

Comment: @ojblass advice from `meta` is that very basic questions should be downvoted. This is the sort of thing you'd learn in early chapters of a book, or early on in a C course. This site is about hosting questions that will have lasting value to the community .

Comment: Join one of the [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254358/why-the-backlash-against-poor-questions/254361)  [discussions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255261/how-to-answer-extreme-beginner-questions/255335) if you'd like to voice your opinion on this topic, rather than via a question's comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `beads` is an `std::string`, `beads[0]` is a `char`. Hence, you need to compare it to a `'w'` (with single quotes), a `char` constant, and not to `"w"`, a string literal.

Your other code snippet

```
if (beads[0] == *"w")
```

is correct, but it is inefficient and counterintuitive. Dereferencing a string literal is the same as taking its initial letter, so it's the same as

```
if (beads[0] == "w"[0])
```

It compiles, but it's inferior to

```
if (beads[0] == 'w')
```

where character literal `'w'` is used.

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++, double quotes represent a string literal -- the string is null terminated and stored somewhere in memory.

`"w"` turns out to be some random address, which you can't determine.

As you've been told, use `if (beads [0] == 'w')`, which is a character literal (note the single quotes) -- a number, not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
if (beads[0] == 'w')
```

This compares something to a character.  *"*w" is pointing to some nonsensical location.

Comment: `*"w"` is actually fine. `"w"` is a `const char [2]` which decays to `const char *` and dereferences to the first character of the string literal. It is, however, weird and not all that useful.

Answer (score 1):

For character comparison, use `'` instead of `"`. So you should use

```
if (beads[0] == 'w')
```

instead of

```
if (beads[0] == "w")
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix your code as follows

```
if (beads[0] == 'w')
             // ^ ^ ** NOTE the single quotes
```

You want to compare against a plain `char` value in this condition.